# blank page when I started web flutter debugging

Tags: dart, flutter-web

*looks like this* :
[image: looks like this]

I have a problem when flutter web debugging. My launching project doesn't stop and displays a blank page.
*blank page like this* :
[image: blank page like this]

i try too webdev serve, but no error.I don't know what made it like that, because there was no error in vs studio

Comment: You have to provide us some code, otherwise we won't be able to help you.

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/35563

Answer (score 0):

If you have switched to the beta channel and you still encounter this issue, run the following commands

```
flutter clean
flutter pub cache repair
```

[This is a link to the github issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/49482#issuecomment-578621750)

Answer (score 0):

Please, verify that your computer is online. Sometime, the app need connexion to load some js files.